# How to install dynamically python in amazon aws spot instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

Have some Python script to be run on Amazon AMI Spot Instance.

Wondering can I deploy by Python script/remote script  :
    1) The AMI spot instance.
    2) Lubuntu, Anaconda + additionnal Python conda packages dynamically
       on the AMI spot instance through script

Do I need to use Docker to have everything packaged in advance ?

There is StarCluster pacakge in Python, am not sure if we can use to launch
Spot Instance ?

Comment: What do you mean by "AMI spot instance"?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get started with bootstrapping EC2 instances at launch is to add a custom user data script.  If you start the instance user data with `#!` and the path to the interpreter you want to use, it gets executed at boot time and can perform any customization you want.

*Example:*

```
#!/bin/bash
yum update -y
```

Further documentation: [User Data and Shell Scripts](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html#user-data-shell-scripts)